# Where the data of the class' objects will be stored?

Tags: java

I'm having a Class and array of that class' objects and each object has its own values. Now I want to access all the details of that class from another class. Please help me solve this. I've to display the details of FirstClass' objects (say f[0] & f[1]) in SecondClass.

```
public class FirstClass{
 int first,second,total;
 public FirstClass(int first,int second) {
  this.first=first;
  this.second=second;
  this.total=first+second; 
 } 
}
public class SecondClass {
 public void display() {
  //Display all the details of FirstClass
 }
}
public class MainClass {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  FirstClass f[]=new FirstClass[2];
  f[0]=new FirstClass(2,4);
  f[1]=new FirstClass(6,4); 
  SecondClass sec = new SecondClass();
  sec.display();
 }
}
```

Comment: easiest way would be, to provide the FirstClass array as a parameter to sec.display or to SecondClass' constructor. Your title seems to suggest another question though ... keep it consistent maybe?

Comment: What Jakumi said, maybe secondclass would make more sense being called a FirstClassDisplayer ;) But really in this simple example, why not add this display method to the first class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way: by simply changing your display() method to something like:

```
public void display(FirstClass toDisplay) {
  System.out.println(toDisplay.getFirst());
}
```

with:

```
public class FirstClass {
  private int first;
  public int getFirst() { return first };
```

The point is: you really do **not** want to directly expose fields of one class to other classes. Using a getter isn't so much better, but at least it gives you *control* about the fact that a "read access" took place.